# Generate binary numbers in a given order

Tags: php, algorithm, binary

I need to display a binary-number list in the given order but have no idea where to start from. The only thing I could notice is that the difference between the two consecutive numbers is in the order -1, 1, -1, 1...

```
00,01,11,10,110,111,101,100,1100,1101,1111,1110,1010,1011,1001,1000,11000,11001,11011,11010,11110,11111,11101,11100,10100,10101,10111,10110,10010,10011,10001,10000,110000,110001,110011,110010,110110,110111,110101,110100,111100,111101,111111,111110,111010,111011,111001,111000,101000,101001,101011,101010,101110,101111,101101,101100,100100,100101,100111,100110,100010,100011,100001,100000
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is **gray code sequence**. You can see that between any two consecutive digits there is just one difference.

What you can do ?

You can get the n-th gray code from n-th binary number.

Suppose n-th binary number's corrresponding gray code is

```
b[3] b[2]       b[1]        b[0]

 |    |           |          |
 V    V           V          V
g[3] b[3]^b[2]  b[2]^b[1]   b[1]^b[0]

       g[2]        g[1]        g[0]
```

So `(g[3],g[2],g[1],g[0])` is the gray code now corresponding to the binary code `(b[3],b[2],b[1],b[0])`.

Here `^` denotes the `xor` operation.

So this can be written in this way

```
function grayConverter($bin){
    return $bin^ ($bin>> 1); // xorring between the binary value and it's right shift.
}
```

### Alternative way:-

There is another way you can generate the gray code (list of it).

The first two numbers are

```
0
1
```

Then the next ones are

```
11
10
```

The pattern is you create first 2 numbers `X={0,1}`. You consider the list in reverse way `X'={1,0}`. And then with all of `X` prepend `0`.It becomes `{00,01}`. With elements of `X'` prepend `1`.

`X = X union X' = {00,01,11,10}`.

Now you repeat the same procedure with `X` again. This way you will get all the elements in gray sequence.

Comment: How to generate a list of n-bit gray codes? If I try to generate 20-bit codes or above, memory exhausted error is thrown.

Comment: Like this, 2-bit codes => 00,01,11,10; 3-bit codes => 000,001,011,010,110,111,101,100

Comment: @codeit.: Hold on I will give you another idea...ok?

Comment: I’m using the same technique. As I mentioned, memory gets exhausted when generating large-bit codes, say 30-bit, 40-bit, as this uses recursion. To generate n-bit codes, you need (n-1)-bit codes. Need a solution for this. Thank you

Comment: @codeit.: Yes this limitation will be there...you then..to generate30-40 bit it requires huge amount of memroy..keeping all of them in memory is quite impossible...

Comment: @codeit.: Maybe you can write them in file and the process it from there chunk by chunk..but it's difficult. And out of the scope of this answers.

Comment: Anyways, Thank you for your time :)